# How can I select a field from Microsoft SQL Server to send to c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, ado.net

I have a table with `SystemId` as the primary key. I want to select `@systemid` and send it to the c# form.

Below is c# code

```
SqlCommand cmdfindsystemid = new SqlCommand("FindSystemId", con);
cmdfindsystemid.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdfindsystemid.Parameters.Add("@systemid", SqlDbType.Int);
cmdfindsystemid.Parameters["@systemid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
int systemid = Convert.ToInt32(cmdfindsystemid.Parameters["@systemid"].Value);
```

But I don't know the SQL code. It can be something like:

```
create proc FindSystemId
@systemid int output
as
select SystemId from tbl systems
set @systemid ?????
```

Comment: Presumably `tbl systems` has more than 1 row, so what row are you expecting here?

Comment: Yes It has . I want primarykey systemid to be returned.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, @reza . If there are multiple rows there are multiple IDs, so *which* is supposed to be returned?

Comment: SELECT @systemid = [SystemId] FROM [SYSTEMS] WHERE "your unique-selection-criteria-here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call the `ExecuteNonQuery` method from the `SqlCommand` before reading the parameter. For sample:

```
SqlCommand cmdfindsystemid = new SqlCommand("FindSystemId", con);
cmdfindsystemid.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdfindsystemid.Parameters.Add("@systemid", SqlDbType.Int);
cmdfindsystemid.Parameters["@systemid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

cmdfindsystemid.ExecuteNonQuery();

int systemid = Convert.ToInt32(cmdfindsystemid.Parameters["@systemid"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server Statement should look like this. Here `@IsSuccess` is used as the output parameter in SQL Server.

Note: There may be different ways of assigning the value into the parameter `@IsSuccess` as I have assigned `-1`, `1` and `2` as per the logic.

You can try this if your primary column is the identity key also.

```
SET @IsSuccess = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

You can also use the [The OUTPUT Clause for INSERT and DELETE Statements](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-insert-and-delete-statements).

To call this in C# you can follow this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60641301/10532500).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddEditTax] @TaxCode INT
    ,@TaxName VARCHAR(40)
    ,@TaxValue NUMERIC(18, 3)
    ,@IsActive BIT
    ,@UserCode BIGINT
    ,@IsSuccess AS INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempCode BIGINT

    SET @IsSuccess = 0

    IF (@TaxCode <= 0) -- ADD   
    BEGIN
        SET @tempCode = (
                SELECT ISNULL(MAX(TaxCode), 0) + 1 AS TaxCode
                FROM Tax_Mst
                )

        IF (
                NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM Tax_Mst
                    WHERE TaxName = @TaxName
                    )
                )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Tax_Mst (
                TaxCode
                ,TaxValue
                ,TaxName
                ,IsActive
                ,CreatedBy
                ,CreatedDate
                )
            VALUES (
                @tempCode
                ,@TaxValue
                ,@TaxName
                ,@IsActive
                ,@UserCode
                ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 109)
                )

            SET @IsSuccess = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @IsSuccess = - 1
        END
    END
    ELSE IF (@TaxCode > 0) -- Update        
    BEGIN
        IF (
                NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM Tax_Mst
                    WHERE TaxName = @TaxName
                        AND TaxCode <> @TaxCode
                    )
                )
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Tax_Mst
            SET TaxName = @TaxName
                ,TaxValue = @TaxValue
                ,ModifyBy = @UserCode               
            WHERE TaxCode = @TaxCode

            SET @IsSuccess = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @IsSuccess = 2
        END
    END
END
```

I use the below method to call the above procedure in C# class.

```
public static int AddEditTax(Tax objTax)
{
            int retVal = 0;
            DbCommand objdbCmd;

            try
            {
                String strDBName = BaseClass.GetDatabaseName();
                Database ObjDB;
                ObjDB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
                objdbCmd = ObjDB.GetStoredProcCommand("AddEditTax");
                if (objTax.TaxCode.HasValue)
                    ObjDB.AddInParameter(objdbCmd, "TaxCode", DbType.Int32, objTax.TaxCode);
                else ObjDB.AddInParameter(objdbCmd, "TaxCode", DbType.Int64, DBNull.Value);
                ObjDB.AddInParameter(objdbCmd, "TaxName", DbType.String, objTax.TaxName);
                ObjDB.AddInParameter(objdbCmd, "TaxValue", DbType.Decimal, objTax.TaxValue);
                ObjDB.AddInParameter(objdbCmd, "IsActive", DbType.Boolean, objTax.Status);
                ObjDB.AddInParameter(objdbCmd, "UserCode", DbType.Int64, objTax.CreatedBy.Value);
                ObjDB.AddParameter(objdbCmd, "IsSuccess", DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output, "", DataRowVersion.Default, null);
                ObjDB.ExecuteNonQuery(objdbCmd);
                if (ObjDB.GetParameterValue(objdbCmd, "IsSuccess") != DBNull.Value)
                    retVal = Convert.ToInt32(ObjDB.GetParameterValue(objdbCmd, "IsSuccess").ToString());

            }
            catch (Exception objEx)
            {
                ErrorLogDAL objErrorLogManager = new ErrorLogDAL();
                objErrorLogManager.AddErrorLog(objEx);
                objErrorLogManager = null;

            }
            finally
            {

                objdbCmd = null;
            }
            return retVal;
}
```

The value of output parameter in page can be used like this.

```
int isSuccess = Convert.ToInt32(TaxDAL.AddEditTax(objTax));
if (isSuccess == 1)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Alert1", "alert('Record saved sucessfully.');", true);
 return;
}
else if (isSuccess == 2)
{
 PMessage.InnerHtml = "Record already exists";
 PMessage.Attributes.Add("class", "errorMessageText");
 PMessage.Visible = true;
 return;
}
else
{
 PMessage.InnerHtml = "Record not saved sucessfully";
 PMessage.Attributes.Add("class", "errorMessageText");
 PMessage.Visible = true;
 return;
}
```

You can refere this link for the [reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/get-out-parameter-from-a-stored-procedure-in-Asp-Net/).

Comment: Is it answer for this question or different one?

Comment: @sam It might be but what is your finding here? I have suggested the SQL query, called that procedure in C# classes and used the output values into the C# page to display the message based on the returned values.

Comment: Ops question does not talk about all those fields that you have used in stored procedure. So only checking with you. please ignore me if I don't sound correct.